# Getting acks = -1 when I set acks to all in my Kafka producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I set the following property on my Kafka producer:

```java
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
```

When I start my application I see `acks = -1` in the `ProducerConfig values`. Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For producer config, `acks` property of `-1` is equal to `all`.

[Producer config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#acks) from Kafka documentation:

> acks=all This means the leader will wait for the full set of in-sync
> replicas to acknowledge the record. This guarantees that the record
> will not be lost as long as at least one in-sync replica remains
> alive. This is the strongest available guarantee. **This is equivalent
> to the acks=-1 setting**.